# Remove invalid entry in SDK console

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a playground on Windows 7 with the App Engine Console.

I get the following error message when accessing the SDK console.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):  
    File "C:\Program
    Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\__init__.py",
    line 700, in __call__
        handler.get(*groups)   File "C:\Program
    Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\admin\__init__.py",
    line 816, in get
        value = data_type.format(raw_value)   File
    "C:\Program
    Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\admin\__init__.py",
    line 1190, in format
        return value.strftime(TimeType._FORMAT)
    ValueError: year=78 is before 1900;
    the datetime strftime() methods
    require year >= 1900
```

How do I remove that entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug in the App Engine SDK -- it should at least fail gracefully. I would:

1. File a bug report against the App Engine SDK, and
2. Write a little App Engine web script which deletes the offending entry, and run it (sort of a hack way to delete something without using the admin console).

Alternatively, the App Engine console includes a panel that lets you type in arbitrary Python code and have it run on the server. I presume even if you can't get into the data viewer, you can still get into that, and so you could just type the appropriate Python commands in there.

Alternatively, you could just delete your dev appserver datastore (run the dev app server with --clear-datastore, I think). If you are quite invested in the contents of your development datastore, you probably should get some good sample data to make deleting the datastore a non-painful exercise.